# Mono GTK Plot library?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk

I tried to google but hardly find any result.

Is there any Library that are cross-platform, useable in Mono and GTK2 support?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [NPlot](http://netcontrols.org/nplot/wiki/). There are (a bit older) versions for Gtk#, see http://www.mono-project.com/Libraries#NPlot_Gtk and http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharpDetails#NPlot_Gtk

Answer (score 1):

GtkExtra I think might work.
[Sourceforge link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtkextra/files/)